# "Good" Blob search

Tags: c#, search

I written this code to search 'blob' items (text files) on the basis of their content. For example, if I search for "Good", then the names of files that contain "Good" or "good" should appear in the search result.

My code is working but I want to optimize it:

```
class BlobSearch
{
    public static int num = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accountName = "accountName";
        string accessKey = "accesskey";
        string azureConString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + accessKey;
        string blob = "MyBlobContainer";
        string searchText = string.Empty;

        Console.WriteLine("Type and enter to search : ");
        searchText = Console.ReadLine();

        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureConString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blob);

        blobContainer.FetchAttributes();
        var blobItemList = blobContainer.ListBlobs();
        GetBlobList(searchText, blobContainer, blobItemList);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async void GetBlobList(string searchText, CloudBlobContainer blobContainer, IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobItemList)
    {
        foreach (var item in blobItemList)
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(item.Uri.ToString());
            if (blockBlob.Name.Contains(".txt"))
            {
                await Search(searchText, blockBlob);
            }
        }
    }


    private async static Task Search(string searchText, CloudBlockBlob blockBlob)
    {
        string text = await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
        if (text.ToLower().IndexOf(searchText.ToLower()) != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result : " + num + " => " + blockBlob.Name.Substring(blockBlob.Name.LastIndexOf('/') + 1));
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

I think `blobContainer.ListBlobs();` is blocking code because search will not work until all the blob item is loaded. Is there anyway to optimize that, or anything else in my code?

Comment: Optimize against what?  What specific problem are you having?  Please [edit] your question to explain what issues you are experiencing and why you think the code should be improved.

Comment: A lot of the time it isn't worth optimizing heavy IO based activity, because 99% of your time is disk reads. Profile it, and see what the results tell you.

Comment: @GlenH7 I written in my question blobContainer.ListBlobs(); is much time to download all blob item & it will increase as blob items increases.

Comment: @Phosi How i can do this. Please give some description.

Comment: Please grab a book on [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) and start reading it. A short description is that you will *index* your data as each piece of data comes in. The *index* is about things that you would later want to search on, such as words, terms and specific numbers. The more specific you know what you will search on, the more efficient *indexing* will be. Later, your query is made against the *index*, instead of having to go over the entire data set again.

Comment: Simple answer: just use Lucene

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

1. `blobContainer.ListBlobs()` is what is taking a long time
2. `ListBlobs` is not code that you control or can improve
3. There isn't a way to perform the filtering you want without calling `ListBlobs`

It follows that there isn't any way to appreciably improve your program without fundamentally altering your approach.  As the comments suggest, indexing is one common approach, either a simple solution you implement yourself or an integration with an existing software package (depending on your needs and requirements).